# PyInstaller Exclude modules GUI

Tags: user-interface, plot, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an .exe file with a GUI to do a plot. 
The idea is that when I click "Submit" the plot will pop up, if I then click "Submit" again, the plot should close and open again.

However, When I click "Submit" the plot shows up correctly, but I need to close the plot window manually for the button to release again?

I've cleaned up my code to only contain the essentials:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # import plot functions
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from Tkinter import *
plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')

################################ TKINTER GUI ##################################

root = Tk()

label_1 = Label(root, text="File name:")
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_1.insert(0,"Input")
label_1.grid(sticky=E)
entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)

def saveentry():
    plt.close()
    name1 = entry_1.get()

################################### PLOTTING ##################################

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') 

    plt.show(fig)

Button_1 = Button(root, text="Submit", command=saveentry)
Button_1.grid(row=7,column=0, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()

# END OF SCRIPT
```

I'm using Pyinstaller to freeze the script, and it's been pointed out to me that I probably need to exclude the Qt library stuff. 
However, how do I determine what to exlude?

I've tried to exclude the PyQT4 module but then the exe file doesn't work. I also tried excluding Qt4Agg and Qt5Agg, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to exclude anything.
(Might be a good idea to trim the included packages a bit though, as the .exe file is a whopping 260mb)

However, I updated my Python version from 2.7 to 3.6 and updated a little bit of the code.

Now everything works like a charm.